# Set Value to TextView directly using Robotium?

Tags: android, textview, robotium

I am stuck at a situation where I need to write a test case to set text to a Textview directly and not to an EditText.

I can not do a **solo.enterText()** as the enterText() takes an **EditText** as its first parameter.

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly sure that `solo.enterText` works  only with `EditText` views.

You need to mock your `TextView` value. It's higly available in unit testing. I'm not sure about doing that in instrumentation testiong using test frameworks like `Robotium`.

Please try to find articles/issues/tutorials about mocking views like: [testing with mock in robotium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194395/testing-with-mock-in-robotium)